# Public API accessible only from website

Tags: node.js, security, express

When a user land on the home page, the website does an ajax call to `api/posts` to retrieve a list of posts.

What I want to do is to make that url accessible only from the site, that 
means even a `cul http://locahost:3000/api/posts` should not work.

I've looked for tons of articles and seems that the best way to do it is to pass a secret token on the requests headers + HTTPS, but the issue is there, that token will be stored on the client side so some guys that know a bit about security could eventually find it.

Ideally I would like to do the checking on server side only without passing anything from the client.

I'm using `express`

Comment: Your best bet would be to use some combo of checking `userAgent`, and using some sort of `token`.

Comment: Enabling `CORS` and check for `referer` in request should help further.

Comment: There is a similar question and answer is already provided - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895679/how-do-i-secure-rest-api-calls