# Rest API login flow and url

Tags: php, api, rest, authentication

I am working on building a rest api just to learn and I am stuck on the login flow and how it should work.

Here are some facts about my api so far:

1. My api is written in php.
2. I am using http basic auth to get the username and password of the requestor.  Once I grab it with $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] and check the credentials against my database table 'apiuser' to authenticate.
3. I also have a table called 'users'.  This table is meant to be the end users that will use the websites and apps that are written on my api.

Here are my questions:

1. If I want to authenticate a user (not an apiuser) what should my rest api url look like?  I have read enough to know that verbs are bad so I am leaning away from https://api.mysite.com/users/login
   So should it just be

   ```
   METHOD: GET
   URL: https://api.mysite.com/users
   HTTP BODY: {"username":"xxxxxx","password":"xxxxxx}
   ```

and just return for success

```
    HTTP CODE: 200
    HTTP BODY: {"id_user":"xx","username":"xxxxxx","screenname":"xxxxxxx"}
```

and for invalid logins

```
    HTTP CODE: 404
```

I think this is the way to go, because isn't a login attempt really just like running any other GET with some parameters?  In other words, would authenticating be any different than doing something like

```
    HTTP METHOD: GET
    URL: https://api.mysite.com/users
    HTTP BODY: {"age":"72"}
```

**EDIT**

**This api is intended to be used by only me.  The idea is that I write an api and then I can write a backbone.js site, and iphone app, android app etc... on top of it.  It is not meant to be for the public.  So that is why I avoided diving into OAuth quite yet.**

Comment: Pretty good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386930/rest-api-authorization-authentication-web-mobile

Comment: @LozCherone OAuth is complicated.. and scarey.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already decided against Oauth, at least for right now.  I am using http basic auth.  I may use the api for projects in the future but for now it is more of a learning experience.  My main questions are about the verb in the url and if my assumptions on how to execute the user login, not api login are close.

Answer (score 2):

I POST the username and PW to the api:

http://www.mysite.com/api/authenticate/ (username and PW included in the POST collection)

That returns a long, unique token which i generate on the server.

A token is then required in request headers for all other requests.  All pages (except authenticate) require a valid token or they return an error.

A login attempt is then a POST because it inserts a token record.

http://www.mysite.com/api/deauthenticate/ destroys the token (assuming a valid token is included in the header)

(also because the token is in the db, I can deauthenticate a user, requiring another login whenever I want - eg, after 10 minutes or 10 hours)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am wrong at avoiding verbs like authenticate and login?  Or is it ok, if you have a token resource, then you might call it token instead of authenticate.  Also, my main question is about authenticating users not apiusers.  I am leaning toward hanlding the session on the client end and leaving the rest api completely stateless.

Comment: Rest is supposed to be stateless, so yes to that.  In terms of verbs, I think the jury is out whether that really makes sense to try and implement, though perhaps more strict coders will disagree. I'm a bit more loose. I prefer my api calls to be intuitive without being inaccurate, so token would certainly work for me and you could make it a get since you are "getting" it, but I would make it a post since the actual action within the db is to create a token.

Comment: After I made this post I started to think a little more about user authentication, which led me to my next question, please check it out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246744/rest-api-without-login-for-users-is-more-simple-but-is-it-right