# REST API without Login for Users is more simple, but is it right

Tags: api, rest, authentication

I have been learning a lot here about REST APIs.  I just came to the realization that there should not be a "login" included in a rest api.  Keep in mind that I am not talking about the API login, that a programmer may include with the requests to the api.  I am talking about end users.  For instance, there would be no

```
https://api.mysite.com/users/login
```

or

```
https://api.mysite.com/users/authenticate
```

The reason why, is because the rest api shouldn't care about the state of the users, which are no different than any other records in the other db tables or resources.  Whoever builds on top of the api can handle authentication how they see fit.  So in your users table you might have a username,password, and hair_color.  So you can make a api call like

```
method: GET
url: https://api.mysite.com/users
http body: {"username":"foo","password":"bar"}
```

to check for "login", which the api wouldn't treat any different than this request

```
method: GET
url: https://api.mysite.com/users
http body: {"hair_color":"red"}
```

They would both return responses with the exact same structure.  Then it would be on the other programmers to determine what they wanted to do with the info, they could consider it an authentication for a login, or just a retrieval of information.  In short, the api doesn't service end user login, or at least doesn't know that it is playing a role.  Therefore you should never return a 401 if a username/password combo for an end-user is not valid and assume that a programmer is attempting to execute a login flow.

My main question is: Is my assumption and logic above correct?

My secondary question (very secondary) is: If so, would the only appropriate time to return a 401 response would be when "api user" (the other programmers) authentication falis?

**EDIT**

**I do authenticate api users with http basic auth, by passing the username and password through the header.  My questions are aimed solely at "login" for end users.**

Comment: The approach we are using is to have an authentication token. The user must first request a token from a secure resource (via a login form) then just submits the authentication token from now on. It isn't very secure, so for anything sensitive we ask for the password as a query parameter via https again. However, for security, I like the way Amazon does it: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html (we just haven't done this because it is too complicated and would require too much time and effort -- so sayeth the decision makers)

Comment: @ShadowCreeper Thanks for the comment.  That is kinda of what I was arguing against.  It seems to me that it is just another way to remove the "stateless" from the rest api.  I am not saying you are right or wrong, but doesn't that go against the principles of rest?  Why wouldn't the application take care of handling the specifics of logging in and sessions?  Does your api have a call like https://api.mysite.com/users/login ?  Also, do you return any 401s for logging in end users?

Comment: No, we have a GET for /auth-tokens that takes a username and password. It uses a distributed cache on the backend (InfiniSpan backed by a database to survive reboots) to remember the tokens. I suppose to be completely RESTful, we should put everything under it (/user/{user-id}/auth-tokens/{auth-token-id}/semi-secure-resource) but we just take it as a query param and {user-id} as a path param. I would much prefer to use the actual secure alternatives that send only a hash in the header and cannot be so easily hacked via man-in-the-middle, but I lost the argument.

Comment: ...and yes, if the username/password did not match or we were sent an invalid authentication token (they can be deleted and/or time out), we do return 401 and the application then must ask the password again

Answer (score 1):

I am using rest API buy my approach is little bit different.

What I did I am passing username and password as a header parameters rather than data with each request. Using which I authenticate user each time he requests.

Of course I had to do so because of my proect requirement but I think it is a good approach as you are not worried much about security part at certain level.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I think you are talking about authenticating "api users".  Am I correct?  My post and questions were concerning about authenticating "end-users".  I do authenticate API users using basic auth and the credentials are passed through the header also, but I am interested talking about authenticating "end users".  I am not sure of the proper term, but when I say "end users" I mean people who will log into a website on their computer, not a programmer building on top of an api.

Comment: I am talking about end-users only.. for me end uses are the one who would be using the services unknowingly logging in into the system. that is only why I told you I had to do because of my project requirement.