# Allow REST API to be accessible through Mobile Apps and my domain only

Tags: php, api, rest

I have some REST API's deployed on api.xyz.com now I wants to allow all API's accessible through Authorized mobile devices and My domain only xyz.com.

If i set allow origin headers to my site then API stops responding to Mobile devices.Please suggest if its possible.

Also when I try to get consumer IP address in REST API call then it always return my API server public IP in $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] instead of client IP address.I also tried to get consumer IP address but no success.

```
        $ipaddress = '';
        if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')) {
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        } else if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
            if (strpos($ipaddress, ',') > 0) {
                $addr = explode(",", $ipaddress);
                $ipaddress = trim($addr[0]);
            }
        } else if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')) {
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
        } else if (getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
        } else if (getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')) {
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
        } else if (getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')) {
            $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        } else {
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
        }
```

Please suggest why it always give my server public IP even IF i hit api through my machine.

Thanks

Comment: you invariably CAN'T get the user's actual ip address, especially if it's a mobile device. those are almost ALWAYS behind a NAT gateway and the only IP you'll get is the gateway's.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest securing your REST API via access tokens.  I just did something similar for a REST API I created.  There are lots of great articles available for "secure REST API".  Below is a link to one I found particularly useful.  I highly suggest using HTTPS to help secure your API as well.

https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-your-rest-api-right-way/

Answer (score 1):

This is how you normally check for the real visitor IP:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
{
 //check for ip from share internet
 $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
}
elseif (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
{
 // Check for the Proxy User
 $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
}
else
{
 $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}

// This will print user's real IP Address
// does't matter if user using proxy or not.
echo $ip;
```

This [REST API Authorization & Authentication (web + mobile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386930/rest-api-authorization-authentication-web-mobile) might come handy.

Comment: I try setting up header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin : http://example.com") on my API domain but it still allows when i hit from other origins and return response. Why its not blocking other origins when i allowed only example.com

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the way to go is to create Tokens, either Session Tokens or Access Tokens. We used Session Tokens with the WealthEngine API (http://dev.wealthengine.com/api) specifically so that they would timeout. At a recent API event David from ProgrammableWeb had a great demonstration on how easy it is to Sniff Tokens and Secrets from Mobile Apps on the Android platform. This is exactly why you would want those Tokens to expire.